# Saving Neo4j spring data entitiy with generic fields

Tags: generics, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have an spring data entity which has a field of this type:

```
@Fetch
@RelatedTo(type = "HAS_TAG", direction = OUTGOING, elementClass = Tag.class)
private Set<T> tags = new HashSet<T>();
```

When i try to save the entity using spring data neo4j i get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity T
```

I know that i could just change my field definition to be more specific:

```
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
```

Could this be a bug in spring data or am i doing something unsupported?

---

- Full Stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/Jotschi/8387f2fd116427cb9aae
- Example project: https://github.com/Jotschi/code-examples/tree/neo4j-generic-mapping-issue
- Spring Data Neo4j version: 3.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT / 3.2.2.BUILD

Comment: Your code works fine without the elementClass = Tag.class parameter, not sure why tough..

Comment: Yes, I can only assume that the entity type is now determined by examining the generics and not the elementClass.

Comment: Yep. What you try is not supported.